# Proper way to escape/unescape newline characters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Suppose I have a simple text input box. When a value is entered, the jQuery script fires an AJAX request to the server. The value is passed as a string to the server. The problem I am running into is that when I call $(selector).val() on the input box, it will escape newline characters (example: if I enter "test\ntest", calling val() returns "test\\ntest"). I could unescape the value before sending to the server (and modify the server to allow unescaped values for that request), but obviously that wouldn't be a good idea. Does this mean that the server should be unescaping the \\n? Is there a proper/standard way to unescape the \\n values on the server side? I am using ASP.NET MVC. What about \r and others? Thanks.

Comment: Have never seen this behavior using val() or posting many many forms using jQuery ajax over a lot of years. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case , i hope Regex.Escape and Regex.UnEscape method will be helpful for you:

**Regex.Escape:**

It converts user-specified strings into escaped strings to match in a regular expression

**Regex.unEscape:**

Regex.Unescape changes escape sequences. It eliminates the escape characters.

**Source/Example:**

https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-escape

https://www.dotnetperls.com/unescape

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: Hi Karthik, while your answer didn't help my case, it led me in the right direction. I figured out that all I had to do was escape all "\" in the MVC view model string (for the textbox). I used a simple string.Replace(str, "\", "\\") call and now it is working as expected. I will accept your answer. Thanks!